# C# - Selenium - UI Tests - IWebDriver - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

for my first test case with c# and selenium, I want to open the google.com website, type something in the entry field and click on search. The Problem is, that i get an System.NullReferenceException, because the WebDriver is Null. But why is the WebDriver null?

```
    public class Base
{

    public IWebDriver WebDriver;
    public GooglePageObjects GooglePO;
    public PageActions PageAction;
    public Base()
    {
        WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\ChromeDriver");
        GooglePO = new GooglePageObjects(WebDriver);
        PageAction = new PageActions(WebDriver);
    }
}

public class GooglePageObjects
{
    IWebDriver WebDriver;

    public GooglePageObjects(IWebDriver WebDriver)
    {
        WebDriver = this.WebDriver;
    }

    public IWebElement SearchField => WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#gs_lc0 #lst-ib"));
    public IWebElement SearchButton => WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#gs_lc0 #lst-ib"));
    public IWebElement SearchBar => WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#hdtb-s #hdtb-msb"));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found the mistake. It should be:

```
this.WebDriver = WebDriver
```

and not:

```
WebDriver = this.WebDriver
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to follow this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/C-Sharp-coding-standards-and-naming-conventions/

In this case you will not be mixed up with same variables names.

So, the second part of your code would be:

```
public class GooglePageObjects
{
    IWebDriver _webDriver;

    public GooglePageObjects(IWebDriver webDriver)
    {
        _webDriver = webDriver;
    }
}
```